# Make image open url onclick in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Hi I have this code in react using states and hooks, I am beginning with react js and don't know how to make my images direct users to a url onClick event without removing the useState and I think this could easily be achieved. I am providing a sample of the code below which is made of 3 separate files.[image: This is a section of my portfolio website which I want to allow user to click and go to a url in new tab for all images]

```js
// filename == Portfolio.jsx
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import PortfolioList from "../portfolioList/PortfolioList";
import "./portfolio.scss";
import {
  featuredPortfolio,
  webPortfolio,
  mobilePortfolio,
  designPortfolio,
  contentPortfolio,
} from "../../data";

export default function Portfolio() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("featured");
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const list = [
    {
      id: "featured",
      title: "Featured",
    },
    {
      id: "web",
      title: "Web App",
    },

// filename == data.jsx
export const featuredPortfolio = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Social Media App",
    img:
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRKvdHn8GmPGCO0y3SJqNHACygpm0h9VycMHg&usqp=CAU",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Rampa UI Design",
    img:
      "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/702789/screenshots/15054318/media/4ea5d492b7b07eebc9528ff960794879.png?compress=1&resize=1200x900",
  },
 
 // filename == PortfolioList
  export default function PortfolioList({ id, title, active, setSelected }) {
  return (
    <li
      className={active ? "portfolioList active" : "portfolioList"}
      onClick={() => setSelected(id)}
    >
      {title}
    </li>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i didnt understand so well what are you asking for, but i think you just want to open a url and use setState at the same time, so you can create another function to pass in the Onclickevent

```
export default function PortfolioList({ id, title, active, setSelected }) {

const onClickHandler = () => {
    setSelected(id); 
    window.open("https://youtu.be/32udqal_lyQ", "_blank");
} 
return (
 <li
   className={active ? "portfolioList active" : "portfolioList"}
   onClick={onClickHandler}
 >
   {title}
 </li>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all I thank you for the time you took to evaluate my question.

I tested several solutions and the simplest one I came with was just to include the link on the Javascript object array which is the JSON format file I have in there.

I will add the sample code below just to clarify.

```js
export default function Works() {
  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0);
  const data = [
    {
      id: "1",
      icon: "./assets/mobile.png",
      title: "Mobile App Design",
      desc:
        "I have good mobile design skills, ready to deliver a good service to you. ",
      img:
        "https://99designs-blog.imgix.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/attachment_100040756-e1538485934255.jpeg?auto=format&q=60&fit=max&w=930",
  // this is the line that need addition since the hooks of useState manages the onClick action
      a: "https://www.figma.com/proto/rJnb39KhEdW6lVU6zlzPtS/ElectricityCalculatorApp?node-id=9%3A0&scaling=min-zoom&page-id=0%3A1&starting-point-node-id=9%3A0",
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

try with react-router-dom this will help you